# Is every subgroup of the quaternion group characteristic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, examples-counterexamples

Let $Q$ be the quaternion group.

I know that every subgroup of $Q$ is a normal subgroup of $Q$, but is every subgroup of $Q$ characteristic in $Q$? What is a counterexample?

Comment: There aren't that many subgroups of $Q$. Excluding the centre, the only proper non-trivial subgroup of $Q$ (up to isomorphism) is $\mathbb{Z}_4$. So you need only check: is $\mathbb{Z}_4$ a characteristic subgroup of $Q$?

Comment: @WarrenMoore Let $\phi$ be an automorphism and $H$ be a subgroup of $Q$ such that $H\cong Z_4$. There are exactly three such groups so it is possible that $\phi(H)=K$ such that $H\neq K$, but how do I assure that there exists such $\phi$?

Comment: Oh I find one automorphism such that $\phi(<i>)=<j>$. Thank you